# Deploying an application that uses SP.js

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, spfx, jsom

I have a big application that uses the SP.ClientContext (JSOM).

I need to deploy it to one of these 2 options:

1. SharePoint Web Part (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part).
2. A static web app on Azure.

The SharePoint Web Part has a context but neither of these has the correct `SP.ClientContext` variable.

How can I obtain the variable (or something similar)? I would like to avoid switching to the Graph client because of the number of requests that I'll have to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSOM within SharePoint framework (SPFx).

Here are the high level steps you need to perform:

1. Register the SharePoint JSOM API as external scripts
2. Install TypeScript typings for SharePoint JSOM
3. Reference SharePoint JSOM scripts in your web part

Check below documentation for detailed steps:

**Documentation**: [Connect to SharePoint using the JavaScript Object Model (JSOM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom)

Comment: Is there a way for me to use JSOM outside SPFx?

Comment: You can use [CSOM (similar to JSOM) in .NET based applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard). Also, you can [use SharePoint JSOM with Azure Functions](https://markeev.com/posts/jsom-azure-function/) for easy/quick automation.